# Which web forums specialize in LaTeX general discussion?

Tags: pdftex, book-design

What is the most popular web forum specializing in general discussion of LaTeX?  I'm asking for standard LaTeX using pdftex, not LuaTeX or XeTeX or ConTeXt.  But, If there's a popular forum that has general open-ended discusses of ALL TeX varieties, then I'd like to visit it to too, if a large volume of it is regarding LaTeX with pdfTeX compiling.

Background:
I'm currently an end user, using LaTeX to typeset books, soon to be self-published commercially.  They are mostly narrative in small format, such as 8.5" X 5.5".  I've discovered LaTeX is an extremely powerful and efficient system for what I need.

I don't use it within a scientific/academic setting, and so I say that without using one of it's most lauded features: mathematical typesetting, and technical style sectioning and sub-sectioning.

I'm helping plan a small Indie-Publishing outfit and would like to develop some templates to personalize our style.  I could even see developing a class for us, strictly for narrative books, perhaps one day even forking LaTeX for us (perhaps others who might find it suits them too) I'd like to have a version customized for narrative books, that includes a simplified "markdown" environment for writing the chapters of the book with less "code" scattered around in it, then using something akin to "/input{filename}" to typeset it professionally for commercial publication.

Comment: comp.text.tex -- available through Google Groups (and other, more traditional means [see below]): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.text.tex

Comment: You've already got some good answers, but it might be worth specifying what sort of 'discussion' you are after. There's a big difference between 'end user' ideas (which in the main do tend to get covered here) and more 'developer' stuff (which tends to be on mailing lists).

Comment: I guess this question should be locked instead of closed @JosephWright?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The major bona fide web forum is [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/) which is run by one of our moderators here, [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz).

There is also the [texhax mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texhax).

And the newsgroup [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.text.tex).

Answer (score 47):

******************************************************************************

[image: Long, long ago, in the times before there were web forums, when forests covered the Earth and the water was polluted only by sheep droppings, there were things called listservs. And the people cometh to the listservs and the moderators saw that it was Good....]

******************************************************************************

Comment: That's an answer with style.

Comment: @StanShunpike ;)

Comment: Great style!  What font?  Is that LaTeX?  I don't see \ldots

Comment: @user12711 Thank you. The asterisks above and below are not LaTeX - they are there because I couldn't post at all otherwise - but the rest is, yes, pdfLaTeX. Goudy Initials and GFS Artemisia. What do you mean about `\ldots`? [EDIT: I'm glad you don't mind... ;).]

Comment: @user12711 Hmm... 2 people down-voted this ;).

Comment: \ldots don't know why, but  I voted UP on it.  It's got the most votes, so be Proud!

Comment: @doncherry Well, why not? ;) It annoys me that people don't bother adding these. Admittedly, mine aren't usually quite this long....

Answer (score 14):

There is also a [subreddit for LaTeX](http://www.reddit.com/r/latex), which primarily is about LaTeX, though the other TeX variations are discussed too.

Answer (score 13):

There is also the [LaTeX Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/latexusersgroup).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the chat section of this site itself.
chat.stackexchange.com