# RefugeePhrasebook - help needed to produce PDF

Tags: tables, pdf, templates, pandoc

Hello everyone (and sorry for x-posting),
I want to call your attention to a volunteer project that has been very
active in the last couple of weeks, aiming to collectively produce and
distribute phrasebooks to Refugees arriving to Europe and elsewhere.
The project's main web-site is http://refugeephrasebook.de/
The different versions of the phrasebook are being published in
Wikibooks https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Refugee_Phrasebook
And discussion is mostly happening on facebook's refugeephrasebook group and some etherpads.

Currently the project is struggling to produce, small, readable paper
phrasebooks. And each version contains several (around 7), in different
alphabets. As a quick'n' dirty solution, collaborators have been using
web-to-print to produce the PDFs and print. However this results in,
large, ugly, barely readable collections of pages.
(See both mw content and reslting PDFs in en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Refugee_Phrasebook#Print_versions)

I (but i might be wrong) think that creating a LaTex/LuaTex/XeLatex
template for Pandoc, that'd take in consideration the specificities of
the print-output, could be a good solution, since original content is
stored in mediawiki markup. Then one would only need to use Pandoc to
convert from mw to PDF, using the template. Right?

My knowledge of LaTex is very limited to create such template, however i
am sure some of you might be able to do this easily.

Please reply if you are interested in helping out, or have some idea on
how to do it.

Thanks.
a

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE. I'm sorry but this is more a post requiring help for a project than a question. There are boards on internet when you can make a call for a project and have more visibility and more answer I think

Comment: It seems that translations are stored in spreadsheet. It might be more convenient to export it as `.csv` or `.ods` and process that, instead of going through mediawiki > pandoc, etc.

Comment: The user [chejnik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8380/chejnik) seems to be involved in an [Icelandic-Czech Students' Dictionary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/35864) (also http://www.hvalur.org/). Maybe they are able to share some experience if you ask them nicely. Other than that this question (with a very commendable aim) does not really fit the Q&A style here. Some of the formats mentioned in [Which web forums specialize in LaTeX general discussion?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266177/35864) or even Meta.TeX.SX (???) would be better suited to your request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some example of simple dictionary for Syrian Arabic. It uses LuaLaTeX for typesetting Arabic and current version of [odsfile package](https://github.com/michal-h21/odsfile). It is included in TeX Live distribution, but fixes for some recent issues are only in development version at the moment.

I've downloaded your full spreadsheet in `.ods` format. Unfortunately, it couldn't be processes as it is, but it must be cleaned in LibreOffice first. Replace all `\` characters with something else, like `|` for example. It would be interpreted as commands otherwise by odsfile (it is feature requested by some users, not a bug). Save it under some normal name, like `full.ods`.

Now, we can try to process it with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a5page,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{odsfile}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic,syriac,urdu,farsi}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Language=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Language=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\_=12
% \begin{tabular}{l l}
% Syrian & Translations\endhead
\begin{description}
  \includespread[file=full.ods,range=a4:az70,
  rowtemplate={\item[{\huge\textarabic{-{2}}}] {\textit{English}: -{6}; \textit{German}: -{1}; \textit{French}: -{7};}}]
\end{description}
% \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Some important moments:

```
\documentclass[a5page,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
```

this defines the layout. You will probably want to change that, see [Geometry package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf). With `a5paper, you can easily make a booklet, see [pdfbook](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam) script.

```
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
% \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Language=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Language=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
```

font declaration. You will need to declare font families similar to `\arabicfont` to other non Latin scripts, such as Urdu or Persian. See [Polyglossia](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) package for more details.

```
\begin{description}
  \includespread[file=full.ods,range=a4:az70,
  rowtemplate={\item[{\huge\textarabic{-{2}}}] {\textit{English}: -{6}; \textit{German}: -{1}; \textit{French}: -{7};}}]
\end{description}
```

This will print actual dictionary. Syrian term is a header and translations in English, German and French follows.

With `range=a4:az70` we select all rows between 4 and 70. The most important line is

```
 rowtemplate={\item[{\huge\textarabic{-{2}}}] {\textit{English}: -{6}; \textit{German}: -{1}; \textit{French}: -{7};}}]
```

all `-{n}` constructs will select `n`th column from the selected range. Syrian is second column, we need to include it in `\textarabic` command, in order to select correct font and text direction. I've used `\huge` command because the selected Arabic font was too small. You can play with [other similar commands](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles#Reference_guide) to get best size.

Compile the document with

```
 lualatex filename.tex
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: this seems really promising. I am hover struggling to build the polyglossia.sty. Running `latext polyglossia.ins` did not generate the polyglossia.sty. But this expected, as it is my first contact with LuaLaTex, and previously only had limited with latex. If you have any times on generating the polyglossia.ins please let me know. Thanks michal.h21

Comment: @Andre it is included in TeX Live, you don't need to build it yourself.